# How to use --excludeCollectionsWithPrefix in mongodump

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.0

I would like know how to use the option "--excludeCollectionsWithPrefix" of the mongodump ?

I have some collections name with numbers like this:

```
   registry.logging_event_15313531
   registry.logging_event_143432432
   registry.logging_event_18979865
   registry.logging_event_905998132
```

I would like remove of mongodump every collection with "registry.logging "

Answer (score 1):

I don't know squat about MongoDB but after [reading the docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#cmdoption--excludeCollectionsWithPrefix) something like the following is probably what you're looking for:

```
mongodump  --db test --excludeCollectionsWithPrefix registry.logging
```